# How to mount .iso file

Tags: mount, iso

I'm trying to mount an .iso file of type data to see what's written there, through a linux server on my virtual machine (ubuntu), since when I try to open it through Notepad++ or a similar program it all looks like symbols and it's not readable.

the .iso file was created by the following command from .bin file:
`bchunk file.bin file.cue file.iso`

I've created `file.cue` online.

`file my-file.bin` output:

`my-file.bin: data`

`hexdump -C my-file.bin | head` output:

```
00000010  c9 e5 24 6d 72 78 38 70  78 6f 75 78 6f 72 4e 5c  |..$mrx8pxouxorN\|
00000020  46 56 0b 13 0c 6e 25 7a  c7 8f b7 c3 0d c5 97 88  |FV...n%z........|
00000030  07 94 68 05 2a 01 87 db  8d ab 91 0f bb 00 b0 cd  |..h.*...........|
00000040  12 a5 8e c2 61 5e 99 3c  94 d2 58 14 70 94 72 d2  |....a^.<..X.p.r.|
00000050  e1 02 48 0f 6a a9 f4 71  ee 1a 43 18 aa 5e b3 64  |..H.j..q..C..^.d|
00000060  de 84 e9 d6 80 8a 48 4e  0a 5f 42 05 40 d6 03 0a  |......HN._B.@...|
00000070  8c b5 c8 1c 01 9f 89 b5  39 93 b1 af 0f 74 55 62  |........9....tUb|
00000080  21 65 28 8d f7 b7 22 f7  e5 4f 28 93 39 7f 19 6e  |!e(..."..O(.9..n|
00000090  a0 2e 65 dd c0 98 bd d7  c7 0a 04 97 ec 85 5b ad  |..e...........[.|
```

output of `hexdump -C my-file.bin | egrep '^0000(8000|8800|9000)'` is:

```
008000  77 3b 95 f4 8c 42 65 14  78 9e 63 73 66 64 73 9e  |w;...Be.x.csfds.|
00008800  19 4b 46 ca bc 01 36 19  bd e9 97 eb a4 ad fc c3  |.KF...6.........|
00009000  b4 d0 08 2f b0 83 47 91  b1 e7 c1 ef 66 41 55 98  |.../..G.....fAU.|
```

output of `file my-file.iso` is:

`my-file.iso: data`

output of `hexdump -C my-file.iso | head` command:

```
00000000  78 6f 75 78 6f 72 4e 5c  46 56 0b 13 0c 6e 25 7a  |xouxorN\FV...n%z|
00000010  c7 8f b7 c3 0d c5 97 88  07 94 68 05 2a 01 87 db  |..........h.*...|
00000020  8d ab 91 0f bb 00 b0 cd  12 a5 8e c2 61 5e 99 3c  |............a^.<|
00000030  94 d2 58 14 70 94 72 d2  e1 02 48 0f 6a a9 f4 71  |..X.p.r...H.j..q|
00000040  ee 1a 43 18 aa 5e b3 64  de 84 e9 d6 80 8a 48 4e  |..C..^.d......HN|
00000050  0a 5f 42 05 40 d6 03 0a  8c b5 c8 1c 01 9f 89 b5  |._B.@...........|
00000060  39 93 b1 af 0f 74 55 62  21 65 28 8d f7 b7 22 f7  |9....tUb!e(...".|
00000070  e5 4f 28 93 39 7f 19 6e  a0 2e 65 dd c0 98 bd d7  |.O(.9..n..e.....|
00000080  c7 0a 04 97 ec 85 5b ad  e2 18 63 ba 18 8d 35 8f  |......[...c...5.|
00000090  e9 df 01 8f a1 af a7 e9  4f 03 99 9e 01 4a fe 60  |........O....J.`|
```

output of `hexdump -C my-file.iso | egrep '^0000(8000|8800|9000)'`:

```
00008000  47 52 0f 9a d3 55 bf 9b  b9 9b bc ad 88 de 91 e0  |GR...U..........|
00008800  da b5 cf 84 ff 4b c4 15  35 88 59 97 a7 9b 78 92  |.....K..5.Y...x.|
00009000  df 0c 91 91 99 7b 65 36  3f e0 49 92 fb 52 8d 57  |.....{e6?.I..R.W|
```

I've tried opening it with `Archive Manager` but it still didn't open.

I've tried using the following lines from the comments:

```
sudo modprobe loop

sudo mount -o loop -t iso9660 ./my-file.iso /mnt/iso
```

and I got the following error again:

```
mount: /mnt/iso: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I've tried many different commands but nothing seems to work, I always end up getting one of two errors:

when I run:

`sudo mount -o loop ./my-file.iso /mnt/iso`

I get:

```
Could not open BIN /home/student/xor-with-xor.bin: No such file or directory
```

tried also this [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1518165/mounting-as-loop-device-fails-with-wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock) with my variables, and got the following error:

`/mnt/iso: failed to setup loop device for /dev/loop0p1.`

what could be the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Please add the output of `file my-file.iso` (it prints the filetype)

Comment: To add to the above, you can open a .iso like you would a compressed file. File-roller, archive manager, or whatever should be able to open it. You can extract files that way.

Comment: I right click the ISO file and select `Open With Archive Manager`.

Comment: I am sorry that I hadn’t checked ISO [file signature](https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) before… Could you please add the output of `hexdump -C my-file.iso | egrep '^0000(8000|8800|9000)'`? Is it certainly a standard ISO file? Is its real name `xor-with-xor.bin`? Isn’t the name a hint for processing (as the contents start with `xouxor`)? Haven’t you got any instructions from the file’s originto to open it?

Comment: @Melebius I'm not sue. I've created the .iso file from a .bin that I was given. I'm trying to improve my skills in different CS fields, and I stumbled upon some game where one of the tasks is written in the given .bin file, so I started learning how to open those kind of files. perhaps the task IS to open this file, since no guide online is working, perhaps it's not a standard .bin as I assumed.

Comment: Well, a [.bin](https://fileinfo.com/extension/bin) file can be roughly anything… How does the original file look like (`file` and `hexdump` commands) and what have you done with it?

Comment: @Melebius I've edited my question. Could you please explain what are you looking for? I'm not sure even how to proceed from this point, if I'll have better understanding of what information can help me to open this file, I'll be able to proceed. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I’ve been looking for [file signatures](https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) also known as [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) to check if your file is valid. Unfortunately, I haven’t found anything familiar and I’ve run out of ideas right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo modprobe loop

sudo mount -o loop -t iso9660 ./my-file.iso /mnt/iso
```

Or install acetoneiso,  is a free and open-source virtual drive software to mount and manage image files. Its goals are to be simple, intuitive and stable.

Comment: Try building the .iso file with iat.

Comment: @kyodake thank you for your comment, I've tried building the iso file with iat and ccd2iso, nothing worked... what kind of bin file are those commands suitable for? (image\audio\etc)

Comment: Bin files are raw-data copies  of  optical  media,  generated  primarily  by  the  Windows  applications,  and  if  used to store CDs with odd properties, such as  sectors which need to have read errors when read, conversion to iso  format  removes  this  information, as iso format does not support this.